# Accidentally ran two AVDs at the same time, everything broken now, how to repair?

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I accidentally started the AVD while having one open (created when I called run project)
I got some error messages, killed both AVDs and restarted my own AVD. It would start, but it does not display anything. Stalls on ANDROID loading screen.

Error message when starting AVD:

```
emulator: warning: opening audio input failed
```

Everything worked perfectly fine untill I broke it. How to fix this?!

Comment: Just for information, there is no reason whatsoever why you can't run more than one AVD.  I often have 2 open.

Answer (score 0):

Save project -> restart eclipse -> tools -> avd manager -> launch device -> play/debug

Note: close all avd manager applications running the background/

Comment: I restarted my computer. Then I started the avd manager and ran the AVD. STill the same error. First I get android. loading screen where all letters are small. Then I get the grahpical ANDROID loading screen, which will load indefinately.

Comment: Must be missing files in your eclipse or on your android folder. Did you recently do a disc clean in your computer?

Comment: I did nothing out of the ordinary. Just first run, then start up my own emulator, while the other was stil running. Only worked inside Eclipse, and browsed the internet...

Comment: Mine usually takes 3-5 minutes to load. How long did you wait for?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo adb kill-server` and make sure you have no other stale `adb` instances lying around.

Try creating a brand new AVD and see if that helps. You may have corrupted the file which is emulating that particular device.

Comment: I am running Eclipse on a Windows system.

Comment: Made a new AVD, choose one from the list of standard devices, it still fails. Really starting to get fed up by the AVD :(

Comment: Try creating a new AVD and under New Hardware set Audio Playback Support checked.